# Autoprint FPDF to physical printer

Tags: php, printing, fpdf

is there any possible way to automatically PRINT FPDF into a PHYSICAL PRINTER?
I'm currently developing a POS and what i want to hanppen is in every purchase there is a receipt that automatically prints when the process ends just like in any other convenience store or supermarkets. Thanks!

Comment: I found this link: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-easiest-way-to-print-documents-with-javascript-print-js-cd512594a98c I haven't tested it, so I'm not sure how automatic it can be.

Comment: It would make sense, security wise, to make it quite difficult to send PDF's to a printer without any user input. The option I use myself is a separate program, which can be contacted by the browser, to print. For POS systems a label printer is normal, and these often come with this type of program or plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answers it is very helpful, i will consider it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.